# How to run entityfieldquery on all fields in node that reference users

Tags: 7, database

Is there a way to run EntityFieldQuery on all fields of a node that reference a user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try rephrasing your question? It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want to load all nodes that use the same field to reference a user?

If so, you would use the fieldCondition() method. Something like

```
->fieldCondition('field_name', 'target_id', $uid)
```

See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3A%3AfieldCondition/7 for more information.